# Sort xls file content by mutiple column with data-type

Tags: python, excel, sorting

I have to sort xls file content by 4 columns in ascending order.

I converted xls file content into list of list. Following is input

**Input**:

```
data = """ABC, Do not Consider1, 101, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 99, BIC Codes, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 98, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 25/12/2015 
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015"""
```

**Respective output in string format**:

```
 data = """ABC, Do not Consider1, 98, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 25/12/2015 
ABC, Do not Consider1, 99, BIC Codes, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 101, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
"""
```

First I **Split data to list format:**

```
    # Split data to list.
>>> data_list = [i.split(", ") for i in  data.split("\n")]

>>> print "\n".join([", ".join(i) for i in  data_list])
ABC, Do not Consider1, 101, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 99, BIC Codes, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 98, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 25/12/2015 
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
```

Following is **sorting requirement**:

```
- We have to sort by index0 , 
   if index0 have same values for multiple items then sort by Index2 
       if index0 and index2 are same for multiple items then sort by Index3
           if index0, index2 and index3 are same for multiple items then sort by Index5
```

My Logic was

1. to create string of index0, index2, index5 and index5
2. Create dictionary with key from the step 1
3. Use sorted function to sort key list
4. Again create xls file.

code:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in data_list:
...     key = "%s%s%s%s"%(i[0].strip(), i[2].strip(), i[3].strip(), i[5].strip())
...     data_dict[key].append(i)
... 
>>> sorted_keys = sorted(data_dict.keys())
>>> 
>>> for i in sorted_keys:
...     for j in data_dict[i]:
...         print j
...         
... 
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'ATitle and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'Title and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'Title and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '31/12/2015']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '101', 'Title and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '98', 'Title and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '25/12/2015 ']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '99', 'BIC Codes', 'Do not Consider2', '31/12/2015']
['XYZ', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'ATitle and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
['XYZ', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'ATitle and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
```

But there are Numbers in Index2 i.e. column two and Date in Index5 i.e. column5, so not get sorted data.

Can you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by multiple keys using the `sorted` function as follows:-

```
sorted_list = sorted(data_list, key=lambda item: (item[0], int(item[2]), item[3]))
print "\n".join([", ".join(i) for i in  sorted_list])
```

returns

```
ABC, Do not Consider1, 98, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 25/12/2015 
ABC, Do not Consider1, 99, BIC Codes, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 101, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
```

The trick is to let your `key` lambda return a tuple containing all the values to sort on, and to convert the third column's values to integers by using the `int()` function.

Comment: Yup, working. I sorted by date also. `sorted_list = sorted(data_list, key=lambda item: (item[0], int(item[2]), item[3], datetime.datetime.strptime(item[5].strip(), "%d/%m/%Y")))
`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you need with a single `sorted()` call. The `csv` module can be used to parse the data:

```
import csv
import StringIO
from itertools import groupby

data = """ABC, Do not Consider1, 101, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 99, BIC Codes, Do not Consider2, 31/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 98, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 25/12/2015 
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
XYZ, Do not Consider1, 100, ATitle and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015
ABC, Do not Consider1, 100, Title and Subtitle, Do not Consider2, 30/12/2015"""

csv_input = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data), skipinitialspace=True)
rows = sorted(list(csv_input), key=lambda x: (x[0], int(x[2]), x[3], x[5]))

for row in rows:
    print row
```

This would give you the following:

```
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '98', 'Title and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '25/12/2015 ']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '99', 'BIC Codes', 'Do not Consider2', '31/12/2015']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'ATitle and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'Title and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'Title and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '31/12/2015']
['ABC', 'Do not Consider1', '101', 'Title and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
['XYZ', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'ATitle and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
['XYZ', 'Do not Consider1', '100', 'ATitle and Subtitle', 'Do not Consider2', '30/12/2015']
```